# Angular 6 Input with Blur Event Inside Dynamic Table

Tags: angular

I'm having a headache with event firing multiple times, my app has an alert and this alert still opening after click close forever.

Here the base problem, in a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rpumgc

Thanks
Renan Paiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is the `alert` call itself. It steals the focus, effectively firing the `blur` event. If you use it just for debugging, simply replace it with `console.log` and you're good to go.

I am afraid using modal window will not help you either, as you would still lose the focus.

I would suggest using different event than `blur`, if it's about validation, then `change` might suite you better.